# Is a working CPU required for the power button to operate?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I purchased a computer on Ebay, and it isn't doing anything when I push the power button.

I'm wondering if a functional CPU required for this motherboard to turn on the power supply?
(My old [dead] motherboard would turn it on even without a CPU installed.)

If I short the `power_on` to ground then all of the fans and lights come to life, but still basically nothing from the motherboard.
The 3v, 5v, and 12v rails seem fine.
The power supply stops the moment I let go of `power_on`.

The diagnostic lights on the motherboard (x570 Phantom Gaming 4) says that the `CPU` and `DRAM` are faulty. The `VGA` and `boot` lights are off, but that probably doesn't mean anything.

The listing states that it has an AMD Ryzen 3700x. I have not removed the heatsink to verify. (I only checked that there was adequate heatsink compound squished out on all four sides.)

---

The main reason I bought this computer is for the Motherboard, CPU, RAM, and GPU. The price of those four things separately was more than the seller was asking for the whole computer including a flashy case, a power supply, and an NVMeM.2 SSD.

---

1. My old [dead] motherboard would at least power up without a functional CPU, but this one does not. So I'm wondering if this motherboard is dead.
2. Is the CPU also likely to be dead?

The answers to these two questions will likely determine if I try to get my money back, or just start replacing parts.

---

### Update

I have removed everything from the board, and removing the board, testing between every change, and there was no difference.

Comment: It looks to be dead on arrival. Ask eBay for help in returning for a refund.  Do not mess with it i as that will make it yours with no chance for refund.

Comment: @John Note that it was just some guy selling it. And honestly at that price if the only thing dead is the motherboard I would consider just take the hit of replacing it myself. Also the motherboard was installed with just 3 screws, and at some point it was obviously dropped. At the price I paid, I don't think that it would be that bad of a deal to have buy a replacement MB if that is all I had to replace.

Comment: Im not certain enough to answe definitivelyr, but all it takes is grounding the green wire - so I posit this does not intrinsically require the CPU.  Similarly some motherboards would use power to do diagnostics even in the absence of a cpu and/or for out-of-band management.

Comment: For the power button to operate, most motherboards require a working CPU and working RAM. Shorting the pins on the PSU will make the PSU run regardless of what is attached. Anything connected to the PSU might start working too, like fans and RGB leds. It just shows the PSU is operational. Have you tried the motherboard outside the case ? WIth just 3 screws attached, it might not be fitted properly causing a short. Without extra components to test (CPU, Motherboard and RAM) you're going to have a hard time pinpointing which of the 3 it is.

Comment: @Silbee Part of the reason I got the computer is because I was upgrading from a 10 year old system, so not a lot of parts to swap out. I can sure try removing things.

Comment: Return it to seller.

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks for the comments from everyone.

I went and removed everything as the **update** above states.
There is one glaring omission that I will correct here.

The CPU came out attached to the heatsink.

Which as you might have guessed, is very odd.

Apparently the heatsink managed to dislodge the CPU in shipping. It didn't help that  only 3 of the 6 standoffs had screws in them. There was also a spot for another stand off.

After reinstalling the CPU and heatsink there were signs of life from the diagnostic lights.

(I of course disconnected the power cord every time I changed something.)

---

After installing the RAM and GPU, I managed to get into the board setup utility. So it seems at least the MB, CPU, and GPU are operating properly.

I didn't dare run it longer than that until I get some replacement heatsink compound.